# Pandas Conditional Formatting BITAND

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

i have the script to check aws tags.
For all resource the required tags was checked.
Now i try to color bad tag value.
I use column State to determinate column to color with BITAND operation.

```
        i = 0
        for i in range(len(self.config["tags"])):
            worksheet.conditional_format(0,  start_tag_column+i, max_row,  start_tag_column+i,
            { 'type':'formula','criteria': f"=BITAND($I1,{2**i})={2**i}",  'format': format_bad})
```

When I open xls the condition format was presented but it doesn't work

see [ko.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c-EsViLr3mXtnK6E14VM8cWfzk2wqq_N/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106966081364843441987&rtpof=true&sd=true)

When I edit (open/save) conditional format rule - all works fine,

see [ok.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xEnYMv-99aDk2ymVDv4OmKoZ2NKf-41j/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106966081364843441987&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Any ideas?

Thank you!

p.s. i use macos m2, Python 3.10.6, pandas==1.4.4, XlsxWriter==3.0.3, Microsoft Excel For Mac 16.65

Answer (score 0):

The `BITAND()` function is a "Future Function" added after the original Excel xlsx specification (see [Formulas added in Excel 2010 and later](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html?highlight=bitand#formulas-added-in-excel-2010-and-later) in the XlsxWriter docs).

So you will need to prefix it with `_xlfn.` as follows:

```py
worksheet.conditional_format(0,  start_tag_column+i, max_row,  start_tag_column+i,
    {'type': 'formula',
     'criteria': f"=_xlfn.BITAND($I1,{2**i})={2**i}",
     'format': format_bad})
```

Comment: It's work fine, 1k thx, RESOLVED